# Does Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 support TLS Oracle database connection?

Tags: 2013-sp1, oracle-12c

Does Tridion 2013 SP1 support securing/encrypting Oracle database connection with TLS?

In other words, can cd_transport_conf.xml be configured to secure/encrypt the connection to Oracle database using TCPS network protocol, so that credentials are protected in transit? Where do we set (how do we tell the OJDBC client) the location of the OracleWallet?

There seems to be a hotfix for [SDL Tridion Sites 8.5](https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000008686) to enable TLS 1.2 connections to the Oracle Content Broker, but is there any way we can do this in SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1?

Comment: I frankly can't see why this wouldn't work, as this tends to be handled by the database drivers and not the application. Have you tried it?

Comment: We tried; the DBA enabled TCPS on the server side and provided us with the OracleWallet (containing certificates). We changed the protocol to tcps in cd_storage_conf.xml, but we're stuck on how to tell the client where the valid certification/Wallet/trustStore/keyStore path is. We don't know where this can be set.

There seems to be a hotfix for making this happen in SDL Tridion Sites 8.5: https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000008686, but this question is for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1.

Comment: You may have to reach to Customer Support for more info then...

Answer (score 1):

You can obviously encrypt database credentials that you specify in your cd_storage.conf.

Since your question is based on a transporter, the first thing you would do is to check with SDL support. For your understanding, you can decompile the cd jar under the "com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors" namespace if your above sender is supported.

If your sender is not supported, you can create a custom sender. If you create a custom sender, you can parse additional attributes for encryption. Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dtransport%2520sender&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1531943828130&currentQuery=transport%2520sender&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-57CEC64E-2F11-448E-8E8C-C51C33710F4B&query=transport%2520sender&scope=&filename=GUID-57CEC64E-2F11-448E-8E8C-C51C33710F4B.xml&docid=GUID-57CEC64E-2F11-448E-8E8C-C51C33710F4B&inner_id=&tid=4c36a803-66f8-4978-93eb-d0b4e36599ac&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false). Ensure that you create a custom Protocol schema with the details that you need. This should give you the needed security.

**Update:**

After @Nuno's comment, I see that you are trying to secure the connection to the dababase. There is nothing special that needs to be done at the application level (SDL Tridion, in this case), to secure the connection. Have to tried to follow the steps under [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28337/tdpsg_network_secure.htm#TDPSG90000).

Comment: I think the question is about encrypting data communication to/from the database, not about encrypting the credentials.

Comment: Missed to read between the lines. I have added links to the online documentation to make it precise. Not so much a SDL question, per se!